# Decompose 2D Transformation Matrix

Tags: c#, math, direct2d

So, I have a Direct2D `Matrix3x2F` that I use to store transformations on geometries. I want these transformations to be user-editable, and I don't want the user to have to edit a matrix directly. Is it possible to decompose a 3x2 matrix into scaling, rotation, skewing, and translation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the solution I found for a Direct2D transformation matrix:

- scale x = `sqrt(M11 * M11 + M12 * M12)`
- scale y = `sqrt(M21 * M21 + M22 * M22) * cos(shear)`
- rotation = `atan2(M12, M11)`
- shear (y) = `atan2(M22, M21) - PI/2 - rotation`
- translation x = `M31`
- translation y = `M32`

If you multiply these values back together in the order `scale(x, y) * skew(0, shear) * rotate(angle) * translate(x, y)` you will get a matrix that performs an equivalent transformation.

Answer (score 5):

1. **Decomposition**

   yes you can (at least partially).  `3x2` transform matrix represents 2D homogenuous 3x3 transform matrix without projections. Such transform matrix is either **OpenGL** style:

   ```
    | Xx Yx Ox |
    | Xy Yy Oy |
   ```

   or **DirectX** style:

   ```
    | Xx Xy |
    | Yx Yy |
    | Ox Oy |
   ```

   As you tagged **Direct2D** and using `3x2` matrix then the second is the one you got. There are `3` vectors:

   `X=(Xx,Xy)` `X` axis vector

    `Y=(Yx,Yy)` `Y` axis vector

    `O=(Ox,Oy)` Origin of coordinate system.

   Now lets assume that there is no skew present and the matrix is **orthogonal**...
2. **Scaling**

   is very simple just obtain the axises basis vectors lengths.

   ```
    scalex = sqrt( Xx^2 + Xy^2 );
    scaley = sqrt( Yx^2 + Yy^2 );
   ```

   if scale coefficient is `>1` the matrix scales up and if `<1` scales down.
3. **rotation**

   You can use:

   ```
    rotation_ang=atan2(Xy,Yx);
   ```
4. **translation**

   The offset is `O` so if it is non zero you got translation present.
5. **Skew**

   In **2D** skew does not complicate things too much and the bullets above still apply (not the case for 3D). The skew angle is the angle between axises minus `90` degrees so:

   ```
    skew_angle = acos((X.Y)/(|X|.|Y|)) - 0.5*PI;
    skew_angle = acos((Xx*Yx + Xy*Yy)/sqrt(( Xx^2 + Xy^2 )*( Yx^2 + Yy^2 ))) - 0.5*PI;
   ```

Also beware if your transform matrix does not represent your coordinate system but its inverse then you need to inverse your matrix before applying this...

So compute first inverse of:

```
| Xx Xy 0 |
| Yx Yy 0 |
| Ox Oy 1 |
```

And apply the above on the result.

For more info about this topic see:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Especially the difference between column major and row major orders (**OpenGL** vs. **DirectX** notation)

Answer (score 1):

Store the primary transformations in a class with editable properites

```
   scaling
   rotation
   skewing
   translation
```

and then build the final transform matrix from those. It will be easier that way. However if you must there are algorithms for decomposing a matrix. They are not as simple as you might think.

System.Numerics has a method for decomposing 3D transform matrices

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Numerics.Vectors/src/System/Numerics/Matrix4x4.cs#L1497

Comment: The question asked about 2D matrices